# Can't transmit char on msp430f54

Tags: c, uart, msp430

Trying to send a character with UART but it just refuses to work.
my code:

```
void open_door(){
  if (system_mode==0){
            system_mode=1;
            UCA1IE |= UCTXIE;           // Transmit Interrupt Enable
            UCA1TXBUF = open;
   }
}
#pragma vector=USCI_A1_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_A1_ISR(void)
{
  switch(UCA1IV) {

  case 0: break;  // No Interrupt


  case 2:         // RX_Buffer_Full interrupt

      break;
  case 4: 

            UCA1IE &= ~UCTXIE;              // TX interrupt disable       
            break;
  }
}
```

'open' is a defined char

Comment: can't stand partial sentences and poor capitalisation. Please use standard English.

Comment: This code is invalid. Where `open_door` is ending? Fix this question or it will get closed and downvoted.

Comment: So how do you know it is not working?

Comment: I'm using putty to monitor the com. and it just crashes all the time.

Comment: And that can, of course, not possibly be anywhere else in the code. Compiling code that makes things crash needs profiling. Set breakpoints and/or use LEDs or whatever is at your disposal to prove it's actually in these functions at all.

Comment: Crashes? What? Putty? Surely it's not the code...

Answer (score 1):

```
  len = number of needed bytes to send
  tx_cnt = 0;          

  IFG2 |= UCA0TXIFG;            
  IE2  |= UCA0TXIE;              

#pragma vector=USCIAB0TX_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCIAB0TX_ISR (void)
{
  if (tx_cnt < len) 
  {
    UCA0TXBUF = uart_buffer[tx_cnt++];
  }
  else
  {
    IE2 &= ~UCA0TXIE;
  }
}
```

Something like that, I have copied an example, you can find many of them using google.